# Cramer's V - bootstrapping

Tags: r, bootstrap

I calculated Cramer's *V* by taking the square root of the chi-squared value divided by the product of the sum of all observations and the number of columns minus one. My *p*-value comes from the bootstrapped sample. The question is does the chisq.test() in *R* compute also the chi-squared value from the bootstrapped sample? If not, how to compute a bootstrapped Cramer's *V*?

Comment: Same comment as in your previous cross-post: Bootstrapping a p value is very complicated here as one need to sample from the null distribution. No, R {stats} package does not provide *any* Bootstrap p value. In {confint}, I once added Bootstrap CI and approximate parametric CI for the true Cramers V. P values I'd calculate via Chi-squared test, which is equivalent to a test on Cramers V

Comment: Thanks! What am I supposed to do now? :)

Comment: See update: chisq.test() offers parametric and simulation based p values. {coin} has another way to provide approximately exact p values via permutation tests. Long story short: forget Bootstrap p values and go for any other p value ;-). Or any conference interval. But not a Bootstrap p value ;-)

Comment: This question is not particularly well posed (Doesn't show you spent much time looking into the docs). There are also easily accessible packages to do what you want: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/confintr/html/ci_cramersv.html.

Answer (score 2):

### Bootstrap p

Bootstrapping p values is more complex than it appears. The reason is: evaluating the statistic on Bootstrap samples approximates the sampling distribution *under the data distribution*. But: p values are calculated from the sampling distribution *under the null hypothesis*.

In some cases, e.g., for the two-sample t test, one can center the two samples to have identical mean and then Bootstrap from this shifted samples. In a Chi-square situation, I don't know how to modify the data to do as if the null hypothesis would hold.

### Bootstrap vs. Permutation test

- The Bootstrap is a *generic* way to calculate approximate standard errors and confidence intervals.
- Permutation tests are a *quite generic* way to calculate p values. The package {coin} in R is unmatched to do so.

**Thus: forget Bootstrap p values and go for permutation tests.**

### Tests for Cramer's V

Cramer's V is a measure of association derived from the Chi-square statistic. Thus, if you want to test the null hypothesis of true Cramer's $V = 0$, you can as well use the Chi-square test of association. R {stats} offers the usual parametric test and also a test based on resampling.

```r
library(withr)

x <- as.table(cbind(c(14, 39, 29), c(7, 3, 20)))

chisq.test(x)  # Asymptotic p-value = 0.001091
with_seed(1,   # Approximate exact p-value = 0.000879
  chisq.test(x, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 1e6)
)
```